# Upgrade 12.04.2

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, updates

I am trying to upgrade my 12.04.2 LTS to 14.04.3 LTS, which says is available.

I have changed my source.list file to reflect old-releases.ubuntu.com.

however everytime I try a sudo apt-get update, it gets stuck on  `[Connecting to old-releases.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.17)]` and eventually errors out:

```
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to old-releases.ubuntu.com:http:
```

If I do a `host -v old-releases.ubuntu.com` i get the following output:
Trying "old-releases.ubuntu.com"

```
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16468
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;old-releases.ubuntu.com.       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
old-releases.ubuntu.com. 123    IN      A       91.189.88.17

Received 57 bytes from 192.168.91.24#53 in 2 ms
Trying "old-releases.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53799
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;old-releases.ubuntu.com.       IN      AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ubuntu.com.             422     IN      SOA     ns1.canonical.com. hostmaster.canonical.com. 2017120602 10800 3600 604800 3600

Received 102 bytes from 192.168.91.24#53 in 1 ms
Trying "old-releases.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62127
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;old-releases.ubuntu.com.       IN      MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ubuntu.com.             422     IN      SOA     ns1.canonical.com. hostmaster.canonical.com. 2017120602 10800 3600 604800 3600

Received 102 bytes from 192.168.91.24#53 in 1 ms
```

I have also tried `rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Its not a networking firewall or proxy issue, because i can follow the traffic out of my network. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Does `ping -c 4 old-releases.ubuntu.com` return anything or timeout?

Comment: This question doesn't seem like a dup to me.  Looks like OP is having issues with connecting to the `old-releases.ubuntu.com` which they have already made the changes as suggested in the dup question.

Comment: Yea I followed How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release, however I still am having the same issues.

Comment: old-releases.ubuntu.com times out

Comment: Can you reach the host from other devices on the same network? What's the output of `traceroute old-releases.ubuntu.com`? I'm trying to find out if this an issue with the network configuration of your Ubuntu installation or with some other network component.